# jaxb marshal included class without root tag

Tags: java, jaxb

I need marshal class with included class fields, but without included class root tag. For example I have class Person and Address:

```
@XmlRootElement(name="address")
class Address {
    ...

    @XmlElement
    String street;
}

@XmlRootElement(name="person")
class Person {
    ...

    @XmlElement
    Address address;
}
```

If I marshal it i get:

```
<person>
  ...
  <address>
    <street>...<street>
  <address>
</person>
```

But I need:

```
<person>
  ...
  <street>...<street>
</person>
```

Comment: Did you solve above issue?

Comment: No, maybe you solution is only way to do this, but it's steel bad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A possible solution could be ..

```
@XmlRootElement(name="address")
class Address {
    ...

    @XmlElement
    String street;
}

@XmlRootElement(name="person")
class Person {
    ...

    @XmlTransient
    Address address;

    @XmlElement
    public String getStreet() {
       return (address!= null) ? address.getStreet() : null;
    }
}
```